# Python и архивы

Tags: python, архивация

Как в питоне работать с *.pak архивами ?

Comment: чьего производства архивы?

Comment: Какие первые четыре байта файла в hex ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос сам. На самом деле pak в моем случае zip только в начало записано 70 левых байт (что то типа md5)